# OpenCV : getOptimalNewCameraMatrix() - newImgSize parameter?

Tags: python, opencv

What is the purpose of this parameter? How does it affect the output and when might one want to use it?

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga7a6c4e032c97f03ba747966e6ad862b1
(Search `getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the (typical) case in which the nonlinear lens distortion is mostly of the barrel kind. This means that the pixels near, say, the top-left portion of the image correspond to light rays further away from the focal axis than they would be if there was no distortion: it is as if near the edge of the image the camera has a larger field of view, and this effect is more pronounced the further away the pixel is from the image center (well, the principal point). There is effectively more field-of-view at the image corners and less at the center of the image sides.
When you warp the image to remove the distortion using calibrated parameters, you need to decide what to do with this "extra" image area. Your choices are:

- You can keep it. This means that the warped image must have a larger area than the original one, so to show the "extra" field of view near the edges. But because there was more light at the corners than nearer to the side centers, you have to fill in the missing pixels with, say, black. The result is a warped image that has a "butterfly" shape.
- You can throw it away, and keep only a rectangle within the warped image whose pixels are all valid (i.e. they correspond to a pixel in the original image). Effectively, you are trimming off the butterfly winglets.
- You can keep some and throw away some.

That function in OpenCv allows you to make the choice (through its "alpha" argument), and returns the pinhole camera matrix that corresponds to the warped image corresponding to your choice.